# how to split multiple lines and add them to an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, file

I any having problems separating information from a txt file adding that information to a list and creating an object with that information

The data file for this application will be a comma‐separated (each piece of data will be separated by a 
comma), plain‐text file.  To mark the difference in grade types (Lab, Project, and Test grades), a single 
empty data field will be included.  The first line of the file will contain the points possible for the 
exercise.the student ID will be Strings.

example 
ID,First Name,Last Name,10,10,10,,100,100,,100

Three Labs (each worth 10 points)

Two Projects (each worth 100 points)

One Test (worth 100 points)

the txt file is set up as follows

ID,First Name,Last Name,10,10,10,,100,100,,100

1234,Joe,Student,10,8,9,,100,90,,100

5678,Another,Student,7,7,7,,75,75,,75

9012,Yet,Another,10,10,10,,65,70,,50

object class

```
public class Student {
private String identifcation;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private List labs;
private List project;
private List test;

public Student(String identifcation, String firstName, String lastName, List<Integer> labs, List<Integer> projects, List<Integer> test) {
    this.identifcation = identifcation;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.labs = labs;
    this.project = projects;
    this.test = test;
    }
}
```

readfile method in class

```
public List<Student> decode() {

    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    while (this.scan.hasNext()) {
        List<Integer> labs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> projects = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> tests = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        String identifcation = this.scan.next();
        String firstName = this.scan.next();
        String lastName = this.scan.next();

//help  int lab =      the labs
//help  labs.add(lab); should add the 3 labs
//help  int project = 
//help  projects.add(project); should add the 2 projects
//help  int test = 
//help  tests.add(test); should add the 1 test

        System.out.println(identifcation);
        System.out.println(firstName);
        System.out.println(lastName);

        System.out.print(this.scan.nextLine());         

        Student real = new Student(identifcation, firstName, lastName, labs, projects, tests);
        students.add(real);
    }
    return students;
}
```

the print statements are giving me an output of

ID,First

Name,Last

Name,10,10,10,,100,100,,100

1234,Joe,Student,7,8,9,,80,90,,100

5678,Another,Student,7,7,7,,75,75,,75

9012,Yet,Another,10,10,10,,65,70,,50

they should be giving

ID

FirstName

LastName

etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use String tokenizer with delimiter as ",". You just need to read the file line by line and tokenize it to get your objects. I would have written it as follows.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;

    class Student {
        private String identifcation;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Student{" +
                    "identifcation='" + identifcation + '\'' +
                    ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                    ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                    ", labs=" + labs +
                    ", project=" + project +
                    ", test=" + test +
                    '}';
        }

        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private List labs;
        private List project;
        private List test;

        public Student(String identifcation, String firstName, String lastName, List<Integer> labs, List<Integer> projects, List<Integer> test) {
            this.identifcation = identifcation;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.labs = labs;
            this.project = projects;
            this.test = test;
        }

    }

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String line = "example ID,First Name,Last Name,10,10,10,,100,100,,100";
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
            while(tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
                String id = tokenizer.nextToken();
                String fname = tokenizer.nextToken();
                String lName = tokenizer.nextToken();

                List<Integer> labs = new ArrayList<Integer>(){{
                    add(Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()));
                    add(Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()));
                    add(Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()));
                }};

                List<Integer> project = new ArrayList<Integer>(){{
                    add(Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()));
                    add(Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()));
                }};

                List<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>(){{
                    add(Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()));
                }};
                Student s1 = new Student(id,fname,lName,labs,project,test);

                System.out.println(s1.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend going line by line in with the scanner - store the entire line as an input string. Then you could split up the line using a function like the Java string.split(),  putting in ',' for the separator option. This would allow you to return the string in an array, which you can then sort into your arraylist however you wanted. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) for more detail on the split() function

example (might want to check in a compiler):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String input;

//define arraylist outside of loop :-)
 ArrayList<String> arraylist1 = new ArrayList<>();
 ArrayList<String> arraylist2 = new ArrayList<>();


(while in.hasNext()){
    //store entire line
    input= in.nextLine();

     //Splits input string with , stores each string in an index position in data[]
     String[] data = input.split(",");

     arraylist1.add(data[0]);
     arraylist2.add(data[1]);
     //etc....
}
```

Hope this helps!